# Python - Exiting while loop externally

Tags: python, flask

I am writing a web server that will log temperatures. The user clicks "collect data" on the web interface, that then triggers a flask function to run a "collect temperature" function which just collects temperature data indefinitely. I then want to be able for the user to hit a "stop data collection" button that would stop the collect temperature function while loop.

The problem (my understanding at least) boils down to something like the following code:

```
class myClass:
    counterOn = 0
    num = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.num = 0

    def setCounterOn(self, value):
        self.counterOn = value

    def printCounterOn(self):
        print self.counterOn

    def count(self):
        while True:
            if self.counterOn == 1:
                self.num += 1
                print self.num
                time.sleep(1)
```

then the server file:

```
myCounter = myClass.myClass()
myCounter.setCounterOn(1)
myCounter.count()
time.sleep(5)
myCounter.setCounterOn(0)
```

Ideally I would like the server file to create a counter object, then turn on and off the counter function externally. As it functions now, it is stuck in the while loop. I tried threading only to discover you can't pause or stop a thread. Am I looking at this completely wrong, or is it as simple as a try/except?

**Edit:**

The external file idea is great. I was having some trouble parsing the text file consistantly across my functions and wound up stumbleing across ConfigParsers to read .ini files. I think I'm going to go that way since eventually I want to have a PID controller controlling the temperature and it will be great to be able to store configurations externally.

I implemented just a while loop that looped forever and only recorded if it saw the config file configured to collect. The problem was that, in my flask file, i would run

```
@app.route('/startCollection', methods=['POST'])
def startCollectData():
    print "collectPressed"
    config.read('congif.ini')
    config.set('main', 'counterOn', '1')
    with open('config.ini', 'w') as f:
        config.write(f)
    C.count()
    return "collect data pressed"

@app.route('/stopCollection', methods=['POST'])
def stopCollectData():
    print "stop hit"
    config.read('config.ini')
    config.set('main', 'counterOn', '0')
    with open('config.ini', 'w') as f:
        config.write(f)
    C.count()    
    return "stop pressed"

def count(self):
    while True:
        self.config.read('config.ini')
        print self.num
        time.sleep(1)
        if self.config.get('main', 'counterOn') == '1':
            self.num += 1
```

From my observation, the startDataCollection was getting stuck on count(). It would never return data, so then when i would try to stop data collection, the flask script wouldn't be there to interpret the stop command.

So i moved on to the mutex. That is exactly the functionality i thought would come out of the box with threads. It seems to be working fine, other than there is usually a really long delay in the 2nd time i stop collection.

```
@app.route('/')
def main():
    print "MYLOG - asdf"
    cls.start()
    cls.pause()
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/startCollection', methods=['POST'])
def startCollectData():
    print "collectPressed"
    cls.unpause()    
    return "collect data pressed"

@app.route('/stopCollection', methods=['POST'])
def stopCollectData():
    print "stop hit"    
    cls.pause()
    return "collect data pressed"
```

results in the following output if i click start, stop, start, then stop:

```
collectPressed
1
10.240.0.75 - - [22/Apr/2016 15:58:42] "POST /startCollection HTTP/1.1" 200    -
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
stop hit
10.240.0.207 - - [22/Apr/2016 15:58:51] "POST /stopCollection HTTP/1.1" 200 -
collectPressed
10
10.240.0.166 - - [22/Apr/2016 15:58:57] "POST /startCollection HTTP/1.1" 200 -
11
12
13
14
15
16
stop hit
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
10.240.0.75 - - [22/Apr/2016 15:59:24] "POST /stopCollection HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

So i hit stop, then it collects for 20 seconds, and then it finally stops. My collection points are going to be 5 minutes apart, so its not a big deal, but just curious.

```
import threading
import time

class myThread(threading.Thread):
num = 0

def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.threadID = threadID
    self.name = name
    self.counter = counter
    self.mutex = threading.Lock()
    self.paused = False

def pause(self):
    if(not self.paused):
        self.mutex.acquire()
        self.paused = True

def unpause(self):
    self.mutex.release()
    self.paused = False

def run(self):
    print "starting" + self.name
    while True:
        self.mutex.acquire()
        self.num += 1
        print self.num
        time.sleep(1)
        self.mutex.release()
```

Anyways, thanks for the help. I've been stuck on how to handle this for about 4 months and its great to finally make some progress on it!

**Edit 2**
Actually, just ran it again and it took 100 seconds for it to actually stop counting. Thats not going to cut it. Any idea whats going on?

Comment: `while self.counterOn == 1:` would make more sense than `while True`, I think. Even then, you might not be able to do what you want without some external interference. Your loop could read from a file that the web interface can write to and determine its course of action that way.

Comment: That's actually not a bad idea. I'm not really familiar with python (or programming at all really) so am really just going for a "make it work" kind of approach, but I would like to learn the "proper" way of doing things if at all possible. I'll be having some temperature controlling functions going as well, so maybe an external file would be the cleanest way of doing it. I'll see if anyone else has an idea, but thanks!

Comment: Cool cool. I've used external files like this myself; e.g. for a scheduling system, to manage cron jobs without actually editing the crontab, to do sensor readings, control relays, etc. It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using threads again. The fact of the matter is that you have a computation that needs to run, while another instruction sequence (namely the GUI logic) also needs to execute.

I would approach the problem with mutex's (a standard concurrency control technique) which should be able to supply a pause/unpause functionality:

```
import time
import threading

class myClass(threading.Thread):
    num = 0

    def __init__(self):
        super(myClass, self).__init__()
        self.num = 0
        self.mutex = threading.Lock()
        self.paused = False

    def pause(self):
        if(not self.paused):
            self.mutex.acquire()
            self.paused = True

    def unpause(self):
        self.mutex.release()
        self.paused = False

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.mutex.acquire()
            self.num += 1
            print self.num
            time.sleep(1)
            self.mutex.release()

cls = myClass()
cls.start()

time.sleep(10)
cls.pause()
time.sleep(2)
cls.unpause()
time.sleep(2)
```

And this should output: (or something similar)

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
(wait)
11
12
```